# Обновление статуса пользователя

Tags: php

Подскажите, как сделать (желательно более коротким методом) так, что бы скрипт обновления статуса загружался только при условии, что `$myrow[id]=$_SESSION[id];` если же не равно, то только сам **статус** загружался?

Comment: Условные операторы.

Comment: Киньте пример пожалуйста где можно посмотреть их использование если их здесь нужно использовать.Спасибо!

Comment: @raptor96, не легче ввести в гугл "php условные операторы", чем ждать ответа на форуме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_SESSION['id'] == $myrow['id']) {
    // Запрос 
}else{
    // Запрос
}
```